# Take output from MySQL array and post specific info to different table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, insert-into

Right now my array displays information that I need, but I am trying to allow users to claim the jobs by clicking the "claim button" and posting their username, user id, order id, and setting the claimed info to show it is claimed.

```
<h3>Current Jobs</h3>
        <p class="text-muted m-b-20">These are the jobs either in progress or are available to be claimed.</p>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <? echo "<table class=\"table table-striped\">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <tr>
                <th>Order #</th>
                <th>Order Type</th>
                <th>Order ID Number</th>
                <th>Order Status</th>
                <th>Order Dates</th>
                <th>Order Claimed</th>
                <th>Claim Job</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>";
    $order_id = $row['order_item_id'];
    $user_id = $uid;
    $user_name = $username;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($wclaim)) 
    {   
     echo "<tr id=" . $row['order_item_id'] . ">";
     echo "<td >" . $row['order_item_id'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['order_item_name'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['order_id'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['post_status'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['post_date'] . "</td>";
     echo('<td>'.(($row['claim_aktiv']==1) ? 'Yes' : 'No').'</td>');
  ---> if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
     "INSERT INTO claimsystem (claim_id, user_id, user_name, claim_aktiv)
 VALUES ('$order_id','$user_id','$user_name','1')";
       }
  ---> echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\"></input></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
       }
  echo "</tbody></table>";
   ?>
```

The code I need help with has a arrow in front of it

```
--->
```

When I click on the submit button it does not do anything.

Comment: Why are you creating an `INSERT` statement in a loop?  Are you really intending to insert a record for *every* iteration of the loop?  Also, you're just building the `INSERT` query, you never actually execute it.

Comment: I am trying to take specific rows of information in the array and allow it to be claimed by a specific user.

Comment: I want the submit button to send the order_item_id from the array, username and id of the current user claiming the job, and set claim_aktiv to 1 in the database.

Comment: It sounds like you want to build a form which posts to a page, and on that page insert a record into the database.  (The form *can* post to its own page if you want, you'd just need to use that `isset($_POST["submit"])` logic to determine whether a form post is taking place or not.)  This is fairly introductory PHP functionality.  Have you walked through some tutorials to guide you on building a form and inserting a record?

Comment: I don't want to have a form on the site since all the information is already filled out, I am just trying to use the button to take specific bits of the information and put it to the database.

Comment: Do you want to insert into the database while *displaying* the records?  Or do you want *user input* of some kind (such as clicking a button) to indicate which record to insert?  The code in the question implies the former, your description implies the latter.  If it's the latter, that's exactly what a form post would be used for.  (Unless you're looking to use AJAX instead of posting the whole page?  It would still be a very similar structure/concept.)

Comment: I want user input to post a specific record like you said.

Comment: How would I do that in this situation, I understand it may seem simple, I just haven't worked with PHP in several years.

Answer (score 0):

Since the only information you need from the user is an identifier for the given row, you can build a simple small form into each row.  Structurally it would look something like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($wclaim)) 
{
    // output your table cells
    echo "<td><form method=\"post\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"order_item_id\" value=\"" . $row['order_item_id'] . "\" /><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\"></input></form></td>";
}
```

Note the things in that table cell:

- `form` - Each row would have its own small form, so you're only posting just that one row's value when clicking the button.
- `input type="hidden"` - The `order_item_id` value to be submitted.
- `input type="submit"` - the submit button

You can add an `action` to the form to post to another page, or post back to this same page by default.  When handling the post, you'd just use the value being sent from the `input type="hidden"`:

```
$_POST["order_item_id"]
```

That would be the identifier you need to insert the record.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST["order_item_id"])) {
    "INSERT INTO claimsystem (claim_id, user_id, user_name, claim_aktiv)
   VALUES ('order_item_id','$user_id','$user_name','1')";
    }`

Comment: @PatrickGarcia: You're not *executing* the query.  You might want to take a look at some PHP tutorials for using a database.  Specifically take a look at prepared statements and query parameters, as the way you're currently building that query will be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.